# Java, Trouble with decompiler

Tags: java, class, encryption, decompiler

I have used JD decompiler for decompiling a jar file.
Affter do that I have source code. 
However, I think that it is be encrypted!
I get some class with the name like "Cny3", "JmcU","Ow0w","YrRb","Jhaa","gzL9", ....
Can I decrypt or get the name of class with any software or tech.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: As encryption does not magically make your class and method names shorter (let alone shrink them to exactly 4 characters) you can rule out encryption. If CBC mode encryption was deployed, you would expect strings with a length of N * 8 or N * 16 bytes, not 4 bytes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code was not encrypted but [obfuscated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscated_code) (see [obfuscated code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscated_code) on Wikipedia). Class and method names where transformed to unique random strings to make the understanding of decompiled code difficult. Reversing this transformation is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

No. The source was probably obfuscated.

Answer (score 0):

(Emphasis mine):

> I get **some** class with the name like "Cny3",

If *most* class have good names and there are just a few ugly names, then I wouldn't think of code obfuscation. I would think that some byte-code enhancing tool has generated some internal classes. Or perhaps some other tool which generates classes.

Tools which may be involved:

- AOP tools usually can weave during compile-time.
- Everything wit an APT compiler plugin (Annotation Processing Tool)

**Edit** Obfuscation tools usually also encrypt instance fields and method names as far as possible. How do they look like?